# Get list of merged branches since tag Git

Tags: git

I want to get the list of merged branches to a specific branch, like `main`, since a specific tag, like `v2.3.7`, with Git.

Is there a git command or small bash script to achieve that ?

The idea is that i determine automatically the bump level with semantic versioning since the last release using the branch name that we force to follow a naming convention like `fix/`, `feat/`, `break/`.

Comment: `git tag --contains` with a loop and some other logic is the first thing that comes to mind.

Comment: Those branch prefixes look very conventional committish. Are you using that? If so, why aren’t you using a tool that parses the commit messages in order to determine the appopriate bump?

Comment: We use both conventional commits and conventional branches, and I'm actually parsing the commit messages now. I just though using branch names would be cleaner

Comment: I think parsing commit messages is better. The branches could have been deleted after being merged into the mainline branch.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "merged branch". A branch is just a string name temporarily attached to some commit. Merges merge _commits,_ not branches. A merge has two or more _commits_ as its parents, not two or more branches. After a merge, the branch name of the second parent is usually deleted anyway.